# Validate field input is string laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

In the documentation I saw this

```
string:value

The field under validation must be a string type.
```

But as I understand (from the scarce explanation + the example given) I must validate with a certain string value. But what I want is to validate simply that the input value contains just letters from the alphabet.

Apparently

```
'name'  => 'required|string'
```

won't cut it, because it has to be `string:SomeValue`

So, what is the correct way, to set a validation rule ***In the model class*** that validates against string?

Comment: you need to provide some context

Comment: @Dagon, what do you mean by context? A certain value to validate with, or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `'alpha'` validation rule Laravel provides. This will ensure the value you are validating contains only alphabetic characters. Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex validator for this:

```
'name'  => ['required', 'regex:/^([a-zA-Z]+)(\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$/']
```

([a-zA-Z]+): This means that the input must begin with one or more letters.

(\s[a-zA-Z]+)*: This means that after the first word (name) you can add one space with another word (name) & it can be done 0 or more times.

If you want to force the user to input his first name(s) + last name(s) you could change the '*' character to a '+' character.

This might be a late answer but it still might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use

```
required|min:3|max:100|regex:/^[\p{L}\p{M}\s.\-]+$/u
```

- This regular expression pattern is used for validating a string containing Unicode alphabetic characters, including letters, marks, and spaces.
- The pattern starts with ^ which means the start of the string, followed by [\p{L}\p{M}\s.-]+, which is the character class that matches one or more occurrences of Unicode alphabetic characters (\p{L}), marks (\p{M}), spaces (\s), hyphen (-), and dot (.) characters.
- The + sign after the character class specifies that it should match at least one occurrence of the characters within the character class.
- List item